# Laravel - When retrieving the distance when given a user's longitude & latitude, I keep getting the same result on all models. Why?

Tags: mysql, laravel, geometry, geo, haversine

I have a JSON column in my database that stores longitude and latitude coordinates set up as:

```
_geoloc:{lat: 33.6556324, lng: -117.7015161}.
```

I am trying to query the database with a user's longitude & latitude coordinates to retrieve all records that fall within a certain distance. Below is the function that I am using, however all results are returning the same distance of 7797.5012454514 with each model. I would like to pass the `$distance` parameter as miles.

```
protected function get_locations( $latitude, $longitude, $distance = 8000 ) {
    $results= my_table::select( 'my_table.*' )
        ->selectRaw( '(3959 * (acos( cos( radians(?) )
            * cos( radians( "_geoloc->lat" ) )
            * cos( radians( "_geoloc->lng" ) - radians(?))
            + sin( radians( ? ) )
            * sin( radians( "_geoloc->lat" ) ) ) ) )
        AS distance', [ $latitude, $longitude, $latitude ] )
        ->havingRaw( "distance< ?", [ $distance ] )
        ->groupBy( 'first_name' )
        ->get();
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else comes across the same problem. The solution requires a JSON_EXTRACT to be used in the query along with a $ symbol to tokenize the object.

```
protected function get_locations( $latitude, $longitude, $distance = 20 ) {
    $results = ( new my_table)->having( 'distance', '<', $distance )
                                      ->select( DB::raw( "*,
                 (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS($latitude))
                       * COS(RADIANS(JSON_EXTRACT(`_geoloc`,'$.lat')))
                       * COS(RADIANS($longitude) - RADIANS(JSON_EXTRACT(`_geoloc`,'$.lng')))
                       + SIN(RADIANS($latitude))
                       * SIN(RADIANS(JSON_EXTRACT(`_geoloc`,'$.lat'))))) AS distance" )
                                      )->orderBy( 'distance', 'asc' )
                                      ->get();
    return $results
}
```